# Delegation not working Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, protocols, delegation

I'm trying to implement the delegation pattern on Swift. The process consists in a popover that is displayed from a UIMenuItem in a text selection on a textView. This popover is a TableViewController that contains some colors. When a cell (or color) is tapped, the selected text changes its color from black to the selected color. I have the following protocol in the sending class:

```
protocol SelectedColorDelegate {
func didSelectColorCell(color: UIColor)
}
```

Then in the sending class I created this property:

```
var colorCellDelegate: SelectedColorDelegate?
```

In the method didSelectRowAtIndexPath of the tableViewController (popover) that is the sending class, I assigned the required parameter:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let color = arrayOfColorValues[indexPath.row]
    self.colorCellDelegate?.didSelectColorCell(color: color)
}
```

In my receiving class that is a ViewController I set the protocol SelectedColorDelegate, and conformed to it with this method, aimed to change the textColor:

```
func didSelectColorCell(color: UIColor) {
    let textRange = noteTextView.selectedRange
    let string = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: noteTextView.attributedText)
    string.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: color, range: textRange)
    noteTextView.attributedText = string
    noteTextView.selectedRange = textRange
}
```

But the last method is never called, tapping the cell of the popover does nothing, what am I missing or doing wrong? Thanks!! :)

Comment: can you put breakpoint in function with `didSelectRowAt` and check if it colled?

Comment: Did you assign ViewController  to colorCellDelegate?

Comment: popover?.delegate = self  ; make sure you assign these delegate to the Viewcontroller.

Comment: @AdrianBobrowski yes, it is called.

Comment: @MarilynGarcía ok then now print `self.colorCellDelegate` in function with `didSelectRowAt` i think this delegate is nil

Comment: @AdrianBobrowski yep, it is nil, how can I assign it to theViewController? I'm a beginner hahaha

Comment: @MarilynGarcía look for my answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all define your protocol as only for classes

```
protocol SelectedColorDelegate: class {
    func didSelectColorCell(color: UIColor)
}
```

Secondly we want our delegate to be **weakly** retained

```
weak var colorCellDelegate: SelectedColorDelegate?
```

Finally set delegate when you show other view or in viewDidLoad eg:

```
class YourViewController: SelectedColorDelegate {
    final override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.colorCellDelegate = self
    }
}
```

[Tutorial - How To Make Weak Delegates In Swift](https://www.natashatherobot.com/ios-weak-delegates-swift/)

Comment: I managed to find my mistake, but if I set the delegate as a weak reference the compiler complains, saying that "weak may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types", not the simple protocol that I implemented, so my protocol has to be a class-only type. Thanks!

Comment: @MarilynGarcía define your protocol as only for classes. Look for my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

In PopOverTableViewController, setup should look like -

```
class PopOverTableViewController: UITableViewController, SelectedColorDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
          self.colorCellDelegate = self
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you do: `xxTableViewController.colorCellDelegate = self` in xxViewController?

And your delegate declaration should be weak:

```
weak var colorCellDelegate: SelectedColorDelegate?
```

Comment: Does the asisgnment of the ViewController to the colorCellDelegate go in the viewDidLoad()?

Comment: @MarilynGarcía, where you create the xxTableViewController: let xxTableViewController = XXTableViewController();  xxTableViewController.colorCellDelegate = self